# Dagger - Accessing Singleton object from other class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I've been working to understand and set up Dagger to handle dependency injections for my Android project. My single (no pun intended) objective is to create singleton objects that I can access across my application. I have successfully set up the objects in the initial activity. Where I am stuck is in accessing those objects from other classes. Here is my setup thus far:

**Initial App Activity**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject SessionKeyExchangerService exchangerService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule()).build();

        // establish the session id as a singleton object
        exchangerService = component.provideSessionKeyExchangerService();

        // test whether I can access the singleton from another class
        exchangerService.sendEncryptedKeyToServer();
    }
```

**Component Class**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    SessionKeyExchangerService provideSessionKeyExchangerService();

    AESCipherService provideCipherService();
}
```

**Module Class**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    AESCipherService provideCipherService() {
        return new AESCipherService();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    SessionKeyExchangerService provideSessionKeyExchangerService(AESCipherService service) {
        return new SessionKeyExchangerService(service);
    }
}
```

**AESCipherService**

```
public class AESCipherService {

    private Long sessionId;

    public AESCipherService() {
        sessionId = makeSessionId();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Session ID: " + Long.toString(sessionId));
    }

    private Long makeSessionId() {
        // this generates a random unsigned integer in the space {0, 2^32-1)
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextLong() & 0xffffffffL;
    }

    public Long getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }
}
```

**SessionKeyExchanger Class**

```
public class SessionKeyExchangerService {

    private static SessionKeyExchangerService exchanger;
    private AESCipherService cipherService;

    @Inject
    public SessionKeyExchangerService(AESCipherService cipherService) {
        this.cipherService = cipherService;
    }

    public void sendEncryptedKeyToServer () {

        // the next line is almost certainly part of the problem
        // but I don't know how to fix!!!
        AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule()).build();

        AESCipherService cipherService = component.provideCipherService();

        Long sessionID = cipherService.getSessionId();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "singleton verification: " + (Long.toString(sessionID)));
    }
```

Here is some sample output:

> Session ID: 217186720 
> singleton verification: 790090968

Clearly I'm not accessing the same object. I realize that at least part of the part of the issue stems from the way that I call the `new` operator in the `AESCipherService` when I am attempting to get a reference to the `AppComponent` class, but I don't know how to get this reference any other way.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule()).build();
```

Nononononono. That won't be a Singleton. Scoped providers work only per component, which means you must use a single component across your application to have `@Singleton` scoped modules that actually share the same scoped provider. In this case, you'd be creating a new component each time your activity is created.

You need to create them like this:

```
public enum Injector {
    INSTANCE;

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    static {
        INSTANCE.appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    }

    public getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

You could also subclass `Application` and create one there in `onCreate()`.

Also

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    SessionKeyExchangerService provideSessionKeyExchangerService();
    AESCipherService provideCipherService();

    void inject(SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity); //does NOT support base class injection! Concrete classes only!
}
```

Then

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject SessionKeyExchangerService exchangerService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Injector.INSTANCE.getAppComponent().inject(this);

        // establish the session id as a singleton object
        // exchangerService = component.provideSessionKeyExchangerService(); //totally not needed

        // test whether I can access the singleton from another class
        exchangerService.sendEncryptedKeyToServer();
```

Also, you're using `@Module`-based instance creation, so lose the `@Inject` on your constructor in

```
@Inject
public SessionKeyExchangerService(AESCipherService cipherService) {
    this.cipherService = cipherService;
}
```

And also

```
public void sendEncryptedKeyToServer () {

    // the next line is almost certainly part of the problem
    // but I don't know how to fix!!!
    //AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule()).build(); //you don't need this here at all

    //AESCipherService cipherService = component.provideCipherService(); //already provided in constructor
```